# Watir-webdriver: I can't click a visible div in an iframe

Tags: ruby, facebook, watir

I have a facebook app which I'd like to test using Watir.
The problem is I can't access its divs.
The is located within an iframe.
I can find it and it even says it's visible.
The problem is I can't click it (it says it's invisible when trying)

Can you help please?
I posted my code with a XXX instead of the user name and a different App for Facebook.

Thanks a lot.

```
require "watir-webdriver"

browser  = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto "http://www.facebook.com"

sleep(2)
if browser.text_field(:id => 'pass').exists?
   browser.text_field(:id => 'email').set 'XXXXXXXXX'
   browser.text_field(:id => 'pass').set 'ZZZZZZZ'
   browser.button(:value => 'Log In').click
end
sleep(2)
browser.text_field(:id => 'q').set 'World Of Fun'
browser.send_keys :enter
sleep (2)

browser.goto "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=277448022299830&redirect_uri=http%3A//apps.facebook.com/worldoffun/%3Fref%3Dts&canvas=1&fbconnect=0&scope=email,publish_actions"
sleep (2)

if browser.button(:name => 'grant_clicked').exists?
  browser.button(:name => 'grant_clicked').click
  sleep(3)
end
sleep(1)
```

Comment: I see nothing in the code you provided that is trying to access a div as you speak of in your title and the text of the question. I see nothing that is trying to specify an iframe as an outer container.  Which step in the code you provided is the one that is failing?

Comment: http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/Frames

Comment: @Devaffair - I would suggest that you cut your code example down to just enough for reproducing the problem. Treat it like a defect, you will get more help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the element you are trying to identify, is not present on that page, try this instead:

```
  if browser.label(:id => 'grant_clicked').exists?
  browser.label(:id => 'grant_clicked').click
  sleep(3)
```

I also noticed that the app is in flash, so Watir will not be able to handle flash elements within it, i'd recommend using [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) or [Project Sikuli](http://sikuli.org/) together with Watir-Webdriver.